# How can I find words from scrambled letters?Visual Basic 2010

Tags: arrays, vba

I have scrambled the letters, so they're different each time and have a txt file which contains all of the words from the dictionary. I am new to this and trying to teach myself VB, but this has got me, so could really do with some help.

Basically, how can I make sure that what the player enters into the textbox is a word that can be found in the scrambled 8 letters by comparing against the string and also the txt file to check that it is a real word? The words can be any length, as long as they're less than 8.

I have two arrays, one for consonants and one for vowels, so the player creates the scrambled letters by clicking on either the vowel button or consonant button.

An example being:
KEEIAQWL
The word LEAK is present.
:)

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to check to individual letters as they are entered into the textbox by the user; if they don't exist don't add them - that way you will never need to check before your dictionary lookup.

A general way would involve looking at each character in the submitted word;

```
available_letters = "KEEIAQWL"
....
entered_word = "leak"
available_letters_temp = available_letters

entered_word = Ucase$(entered_word) '//ensure same case

dim i as long, pos as long
for i = 1 to Len(entered_word)
    '// see if letter ok
    pos = instr(1, available_letters_temp, mid$(entered_word, i, 1))
    if pos = 0 then
        msgboxMid$(entered_word, i, 1) & " is not valid"
    else
        '// ok, remove for future lookups
        mid$(available_letters_temp, pos, 1) = "@"
    end if
Next
```

This also makes sure that a letter can only be used once, i.e. "BOOB" from "BO" is not allowed.